# How to make one table for gender while having different codes for one disease in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset in R where one disease is coded with different code numbers.

Just, for example, let's take code as -

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Gender = sample(c("Male", "Female", "Other"), 20, T),
                 Disease = sample(c("709", "908", "1515", "698", "890", "20"), 20, T))
```

Code numbers such as - 709, 1515, and 20 belong to only one disease named Gonorrhoea.

Now, I have to generate a table for gender and only for Gonorrhoea. I am wondering how can it be done. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `table(subset(df, Disease %in% c(709, 1515, 20)))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any of the first two options will table the required subset of the data. The 3rd option transforms a table into a data.frame with the same information, only its presentation is different.

```r
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Gender = sample(c("Male", "Female", "Other"), 20, T),
                 Disease = sample(c("709", "908", "1515", "698", "890", "20"), 20, T))

table(subset(df, Disease %in% c(709, 1515, 20)))
#>         Disease
#> Gender   1515 20 709
#>   Female    1  1   1
#>   Male      0  1   2
#>   Other     0  2   1

xtabs(~ Gender + Disease, df, subset = Disease %in% c(709, 1515, 20))
#>         Disease
#> Gender   1515 20 709
#>   Female    1  1   1
#>   Male      0  1   2
#>   Other     0  2   1

tbl <- table(subset(df, Disease %in% c(709, 1515, 20)))
as.data.frame(tbl)
#>   Gender Disease Freq
#> 1 Female    1515    1
#> 2   Male    1515    0
#> 3  Other    1515    0
#> 4 Female      20    1
#> 5   Male      20    1
#> 6  Other      20    2
#> 7 Female     709    1
#> 8   Male     709    2
#> 9  Other     709    1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hey Rui, thank you so very much for your kind help. 

I apologise as I forgot to mention that there is one character in front of every code number of the disease. Such as - J709, and K1515. So, when I do apply the methods you mentioned, they work only if the character or alphabet is not in front of the disease codes. Is there any way to do it by keeping characters in front of the disease codes? :)

Once again, I am really sorry for not mentioning there are alphabets in front of these codes.

Comment: @Microbiota_ Yes, you can add the character `c("J709", "K1515", 20)` but then you will need to put the values between quotes.